# UILabel unexpectedly returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Making a basic stopwatch. My model is updating my controller fine but when I attempt to update my `UILabel` it's returning `nil`.

It's only returning `nil` when I'm attempting to update from the timer. If I update the controller without using the timer, it will update the label.

I think I must be missing something.

View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var stopWatchBrainInstance = stopWatchBrain()
    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

    var displayValue:Int{
        get{
            print("getting Display Val")
            return Int(timerLabel.text!)!
        }
        set{
            timerLabel?.text! = String(val)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let buttonId = sender.currentTitle{
            let testVAr = displayValue

            stopWatchBrainInstance.setButton(pressed: buttonId, currentDisplayVal: testVAr)
            displayValue = stopWatchBrainInstance.timerVal
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class stopWatchBrain:NSObject {
    //Public API

    public  func setButton(pressed identifier:String,currentDisplayVal:Int){
        switch identifier{
        case "Start":
            startTimer(currentTime: currentDisplayVal)
            break
        case "Stop":
           stopTimer()
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    public var timerVal: Int {
        get{
            return stopwatchValue
        }
    }

    //Vars
    private var timer = Timer()
    private var stopwatchValue:Int = 1

    //Methods
    private  func startTimer (currentTime: Int){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(self.runtheTimer)) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    private  func stopTimer (){
        print("stopping timer")
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    @objc private func runtheTimer(){
        stopwatchValue += 1
        print(stopwatchValue)

        ViewController().setTitle(stopwatchValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but your `displayValue` property is poorly implemented. Don't use the label as your data. Just use the label to display the value. Change your property to: `var displayValue = 0 { didSet { timerLabel = String(displayValue) } }`.

Comment: noted thanks maddy

Comment: @rmaddy you meant `timerLabel.text = String(displayValue)`

Comment: @SusanHo Dont force unwrap the Int initializer. The text input might not be a valid integer.Use the nil coalescing operator to return a default value in case of failure. `return Int(timerLabel.text!) ?? 0`

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, thanks. We need a good code completion / compiler plugin for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
ViewController().setTitle(stopwatchValue)
```

Do you know what it does? It makes a completely new and separate ViewController object (not the one in the interface), calls its `setTitle` method, and throws it away.

Comment: ahhhhh that makes sense. So how do i call the view controller that i want?

Comment: @SusanHo You need to give StopWatchBrain a (weak) reference to your view controller when you create it, so that it has a way to find the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Matt gave you the main flaw with your code, although there are some other messes to clean up as well.

As for how your `StopWatchBrain` would call your view controller, this would be a good use case for the delegate design pattern. Read up on that. You'd give your `StopWatchBrain` class a delegate that it would call when the value changes.

You'd make the view controller the delegate of the `StopWatchBrain` and it would update it's label when it's delegate method gets called with a new timer value.